# Remove extra characters from DateField in Django Admin form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to have the DateField (created_at/updated_at) I have set up to be a readonly field that I can access through both the list_display and the form for adding in Django Admin. The way I have it set up it's showing as:

```
%09/%24/%2018
```

I know it's pulling from DATE_FORMAT in settings.py:

```
DATE_FORMAT = '%m/%d/%Y'
```

I just haven't figured out how to remove the **%** before it is displayed in Admin. Is there a way to clean this up? I've tried already to access the created_at/updated_at fields to write an algorithm to remove the extra characters, but can't seem to extract the values.

Here is my code if that helps. Thanks in advance!

### admin.py

```
class BatchForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Batch
        fields = '__all__'

class BatchAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = BatchForm
    readonly_fields = ('created_at', 'updated_at')
    list_display = ('item', 'active',  'desc', 'quantity', 'created_at', 'updated_at')
```

### models.py

```
class Batch(models.Model):
    created_at      = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at      = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: This looks very weird, normally there are no such `%`s. Are you sure you did not wrote `%%%m/%%%d/%%%Y` somewhere in the settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/), for the DATE_FORMAT, you do not need to put the `%`. So you would actually want to simply put `DATE_FORMAT = 'm/d/Y'`

Comment: Ah right on thanks.. I thought for a second that because the DATE_FORMAT value wasn't turning purple in my editor that I did something wrong, and remembered that I had initially changed it to ['%m/%d/%Y'] so I could control the format of the DateField for my User model's DOB. To have both I added another DATE_FORMAT to settings and referenced it in with admin.py: dob = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(format = '%m/%d/%Y', attrs={'placeholder':'mm/dd/yyyy'}), input_formats=settings.DATE_FORMAT_CUSTOM)

Comment: I definitely understand. Its kinda confusing because it doesn't follow traditional python date-string formatting. But looks like a good idea!